# Split the string based on specific text - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this string in one of the cell in Oracle table - table1

```
MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|19620320|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^GLUCOSE|||200202150730|||||||||
 555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBX|2|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^172|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
FT1|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBR|2|423525^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^PROTEIN|||200202150730|||||||||
 555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBX|2|SN|434-5^PROTEIN1^POST 13H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^132|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBX|3|SN|434-5^PROTEIN2^POST 14H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
FT1|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
```

I need to break this down in the following table:

table2

```
SEQ       MESSAGE
1         MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
          PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|19620320|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
          OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^GLUCOSE|||200202150730|||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
          OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
          OBX|2|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^172|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
          FT1|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F

2         MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
          PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|19620320|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
          OBR|2|423525^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^PROTEIN|||200202150730|||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
          OBX|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
          OBX|2|SN|434-5^PROTEIN1^POST 13H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^132|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
          OBX|3|SN|434-5^PROTEIN2^POST 14H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
          FT1|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
```

Basically I need to scan for OBR and break the message but always prepend MSH and PID to messages.

Can someone help to code in Oracle SQL?

Comment: What's your query attempt? All your past questions seem to be of the type *"give me my query"*.

Comment: I have tried doing in SQL, but I failed and have no idea that it could be done in Oracle SQL. I'm looking for direction here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE test_data ( value ) AS
SELECT 'MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|19620320|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^GLUCOSE|||200202150730|||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBX|2|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^172|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
FT1|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBR|2|423525^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^PROTEIN|||200202150730|||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
OBX|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBX|2|SN|434-5^PROTEIN1^POST 13H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^132|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
OBX|3|SN|434-5^PROTEIN2^POST 14H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
FT1|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F'
FROM   DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, '^MSH.*?' || CHR(10) || 'PID.*?' || CHR(10) )
         || REGEXP_SUBSTR( t.value, 'OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*', 1, c.COLUMN_VALUE ) AS split_value
FROM   test_data t
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT( t.value, 'OBR.*?' || CHR(10) || '((OBX|FT1).*?($|' || CHR(10) || '))*' )
           ) AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       ) c
       ON ( 1 = 1 );
```

**Output**:

```
| SPLIT_VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      |
| :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
| PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|19620320|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
| OBR|1|845439^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^GLUCOSE|||200202150730|||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
| OBX|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
| OBX|2|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^172|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
| FT1|1|SN|1554-5^GLUCOSE^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
|
| :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| MSH|^~\&|GHH LAB|ELAB-3|GHH OE|BLDG4|200202150930||ORU^R01|CNTRL-3456|P|2.4
| PID|||555-44-4444||EVERYWOMAN^EVE^E^^^^L|JONES|19620320|F|||153 FERNWOOD DR.^^STATESVILLE^OH^35292||(206)3345232|(206)752-121||||AC555444444||67-A4335^OH^20030520
| OBR|2|423525^GHH OE|1045813^GHH LAB|15545^PROTEIN|||200202150730|||||||||555-55-5555^PRIMARY^PATRICIA P^^^^MD^^|||||||||F||||||444-44-4444^HIPPOCRATES^HOWARD H^^^^MD
| OBX|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
| OBX|2|SN|434-5^PROTEIN1^POST 13H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^132|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
| OBX|3|SN|434-5^PROTEIN2^POST 14H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
| FT1|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F
|
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b3bd141f47f7bb0fee09c2f5c1f10242)*

Comment: How about adding sequence as first column?

Comment: Also, the last line - "FT1|1|SN|434-5^PROTEIN^POST 12H CFST:MCNC:PT:SER/PLAS:QN||^182|mg/dl|70_105|H|||F" is missing in the second row. How can I get that?

Comment: @dang Updated to show the last line. Just include `c.COLUMN_VALUE AS seq` in the columns selected if you want the sequence.